# Remove a cordova plugin

Tags: cordova

I am having issues trying to use Onesignal for Ionic because I am getting the following error regarding FCM plugin which I attempted to use for notifications before :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cordova-plugin-fcm: You have installed platform android but file 'google-services.json' was not found in your Cordova project root folder.
(node:13416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I want to try and remove the FCM plugin entirely and see if that fixes it, however I am unable to do so.

When I run `sudo cordova plugin` I see the following for FCM:
`cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin`

I have tried to remove by doing `sudo cordova plugin remove FCM` and `sudo cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"` but neither works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-fcm --force` other wise just download the google-services.json file from Firebase and place it in the root of your project and try again.

Answer (score 3):

If the above solution didn't work and you got any unhandled promise rejection then try to follow steps :
 1. Clean the Cordova project

```
cordova clean
```

2. Remove platform

`cordova platform remove android/ios`

3.Then remove plugin

```
cordova plugin remove <plugin name>
```

4. add platforms and run the project

It worked for me.

Comment: Yep, the line cordova plugin remove <plugin name> worked for me to remove a camera plugin.